# Python Subprocess.run Seemingly does Nothing

Tags: python, subprocess

I am writing a wrapper script to make generation of random maps for a game more convenient. The idea is to be able to let the game generate a bunch of maps while I go do something else (as it can take quite a while with large maps).
Here is the script: https://pastebin.com/MSLc9C3J

The important part is:

```py
command_str = ['Dominions5.exe', '--makemap', f'{args.mapname}']

    command_str.append('--mapsize')
    command_str.append(str(args.width))
    command_str.append(str(args.height))

    exclude_args = ['mapname', 'width', 'height', 'hwrap', 'vwrap', 'nummaps']

    for arg in vars(args):
        if arg not in exclude_args:
            command_str.append('--' + arg)
            command_str.append(str(getattr(args, arg)))

    if not args.hwrap:
        command_str.append('--nohwrap')

    if args.vwrap:
        command_str.append('--vwrap')

    nummaps = args.nummaps

    for x in range(nummaps):
        command_str[2] = args.mapname if x == 0 else args.mapname + str(x)
        cmd = ' '.join(command_str)
        subprocess.run(split(cmd), shell=True, capture_output=True)
```

Running this script on the command-line produces no output, and I can see no instances of Dominions5 running in taskmanager. I have tried passing the run arguments differently, (with the cmd as a string, without shell-True, etc.) but have not gotten a different result. I have also tried doing the same with Popen (which I would like to try to get working as well, just to see how well this works when the maps are generated in parallel).

How do I make subprocess.run work as I want?

Comment: The output is being captured, not displayed, and you are not using the result value of `subprocess.run` in any way. Secondary, but why `join` then `split`? Just pass `command_str` list directly to `subprocess.run`. (Also, why is a list called `command_str`?)

Comment: i think it's best to see the output of `subprocess.run` as in the answer, you'll most likely find something like "command XX not found" , so you'll know you were in the wrong directory, and you will need to pass the full app path, this is why `shell=True` is usually bad if you aren't passing shell commands, also post the error you get when you use `shell=False`

Comment: How about clicking [edit] and 1) showing the command you would normally run in the shell along with its output and 2) adding a `print()` statement in your Python showing the command just before you run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things that may help:

1. if you are going to split your command into a list of strings, then make `shell = False`, if you use the command as a whole (a single `string`), use `shell = True`. So...

   either: `subprocess.run(split(cmd), shell = False...` or `subprocess.run(command_str, shell = True...`
2. if you want to see the standard output of your `subprocess.run` either

   - make `capture_output = False` or,
   - capture the output and print it after command execution:

```
c = subprocess.run(command_str, shell=True, capture_output=True)
print(c.stdout)
```

Comment: Thanks. After taking the generated command string and messing about with it for a while, I found a bug with one of the command line options was preventing the map from generating, which I have reported to the developers.